# How to delete lines after the last \n\n\n\n by python

Tags: python

How to delete lines after the last \n\n\n\n?

```
text = """
zzzz zzz zzz zz zzzz zzz  z
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzz



zzzzzzz zzzzzzzzz zz zzzzz zzzzz zzz
zzzzzzz zzz zz z z zz zzzz zzzzz z
zz zzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzzz zzzz



zzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzz
zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzzzzz
zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz  zzzzzzz zzzzz zzzz
"""
```

> Desired output is:

```
text = """
zzzz zzz zzz zz zzzz zzz  z
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzz



zzzzzzz zzzzzzzzz zz zzzzz zzzzz zzz
zzzzzzz zzz zz z z zz zzzz zzzzz z
zz zzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzzz zzzz
"""
```

> i think i need some kind of loop for finish this code?

```
result = ' '.join(map(str, text))
length = result.count('\n\n\n\n')
```

but i guess there is a some python library i didnt know..

or any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```py
sep = "\n\n\n\n"
print(sep.join(text.split(sep)[:-1]))
```

Or, a more efficient solution, as suggested:

```py
text.rsplit(sep, 1)[0]
```

Comment: As shown in the dup question, `text.rsplit(sep, 1)[0]` is cleaner and faster.

Comment: Indeed, edited my answer, thanks